# How to use composer project on server without composer

Tags: composer-php

I have Composer installed on my computer to manage the dependencies, but I am on a shared hosting account without SSH access to install Composer. How would I go about uploading this project to the server without Composer?

The project is a PHP project with Amazon and other libraries and APIs.

Comment: You don't need Composer on the live server, you only need his autoloader, so you can install dependencies through Composer on your local machine and then you upload everything via FTP.

Comment: When I have the use clause in my script i get a parsing error?

Comment: @AlexandruGuzinschi, everything upload? please a example. thanks from Vienna

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, you don't need composer on your production server, in this case.
What you can do, if not done already, is run `composer update` on ANOTHER (maybe local) dev machine and test your application.

If everything is OK, upload all files (yes, vendor and all) to your host.